# How to view status of code at any given git commit on a branch?

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a master branch where I have several month of commits relating to a web project.

I sometimes need to see what the site looks like via a browser at given points in the past.

I currently checkout master branch, select the point in time and create a branch. I can then see the site in a browser at that point in time.

Is that how I should be doing it or is there a more simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is one of the ways to do it.
There are a couple of ways to get there faster (*just a tiny bit*).

1. If you have some kind of web UI to view the repository and associated commits (if your repository is hosted on GitHub or BitBucket, for example) you could figure out the commit SHA1 hash and perform a checkout by hash. The command would be:

   ```
   git checkout <sha1>
   ```

---

2. If you are interested in the state relative to a point in time you could use a simple command to first find the "closest" commit hash and then check it out. For example, if you need to look at the state of the code at 1st of March, 2017, you are actually interested in the latest commit that happened before 03/01/2017 00:00. The command would be:

   ```
   git checkout `git rev-list -n 1 --before="2017-03-01 00:00" master
   ```

   It's important to mention that you will need to use slightly different syntax if you're running on Windows. Here's a PowerShell version of the same code:

   ```
   $sha = git rev-list -1 --before="2017-03-01 00:00" master
   git checkout $sha
   ```

---

3. Finally, if you know that a certain commit represents one of these points in time you'll need/want to come back to in the future, you can use Git tagging functionality and checkout tags later. For example, to tag a commit you can run (*replace sha1 with a commit hash*):

   ```
   git tag -a some-point-in-time <sha1>
   ```

   When you want to "come back" to this point in time you can run:

   ```
   git checkout -b master some-point-in-time
   ```

---

Comment: Improved the formatting of your answer for better readability. Tip: Indent code blocks on SO by 4 spaces instead of enclosing within triple-backticks. Also, there's a preview underneath the text-input box.

Comment: I find $() easier to read compared to back-ticks.  Also HEAD is probably a better bet than master (in case they are not on master!).  End result:  git checkout $(git rev-list -n 1 --before="2017-03-01 00:00" HEAD)

Comment: @G.SylvieDavies the question explicitly specified the "master" branch scenario, hence the master example.There is also a caviat with the $() syntax - a lot of CI/CD systems use $() for defining build-time variables and using $() might result in unpredictable behaviour .

Comment: One of the best answers I've come across - thank you v much Phil!

Comment: I think you're missing a closing back-tick.

Answer (score 1):

Running `git status` will provide you with the current status of a branch. Staged files, unstaged modified files, whether in the middle of a rebase / merge, etc

To view the site continuously during development, I suggest using a local server to serve the site for you locally, where-in you can constantly `refresh` the browser to see the changes.

A popular means (also used at Github Pages) is serving the site via [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com).

Comment: I need to see what the website looks like at given points in the past rather than what the status of the branch was at given points in the past. Apologies for the lack of clarity in my qu.

Comment: Is the site a Jekyll Site?

Comment: I think he wants the status of the actual website, not of the Git folder.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, yes, I'm aware of that, thank you. I've updated my answer to the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout the `master` branch at a specific earlier commit, e.g.

```
git checkout <SHA-1 of some commit in master>
```

This will put you into the detached HEAD state.  From here, you can actually build your project, deploy, and see what it looks like.

If you wanted to create a bona fide branch from an earlier commit, you could do so via:

```
git checkout -b new_branch_from_old_commit
```

Most likely, you won't need to create a new branch though.  When you are done looking around, you can return to your current `master` branch by just checking it out:

```
git checkout master
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `git checkout` a commit by its hash ID, though that gives you the scary-sounding "detached HEAD".

#### Background

Branches and tags are ways to name some specific commit.  For that matter, `HEAD` is just a way to name a branch, or sometimes one specific commit.

Hence:

```
git log
```

shows you commits starting from `HEAD`, and:

```
git log master
```

shows you commits starting from `master`.  If `HEAD` names `master`, these two do exactly the same thing.

Adding `--oneline`, or my preference for "DOG"—`--decorate --oneline --graph`; consider also "A DOG", `--all --decorate...`—compresses the output a bit:

```
* e0688e9 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) git svn: fix ...
* 3bc5322 First batch after 2.12
* 3e5c639 Merge branch 'rl/remote-allow-missing-branch-name-merge'
```

Here we see that `HEAD` names `master`, and there are two more names for commit `e0688e9` as well.

Each commit names a previous commit (its *parent commit*).  This is *how* `git log` is able to show more than one commit.  We say that branch and tag names *point to* a commit like `e0688e9`, and that commit points back to its predecessor `3bc5322`, which points back to yet another one, and so on.

If we draw these as a series of one-letter-name commits (much more wieldy than the `3bc5322...` hash IDs), we get something that looks like this:

```
A <- B <- C   <-- master
```

Here the name `master` points to `C`, and `C` points back to `B` which points back to `A`.  `A` is the very first commit ever made, so it *can't* point back any further, and doesn't.  This is how `git log` knows to *stop!*

#### Detached HEAD

Normally, `HEAD` contains an actual branch name.  In the above `git log` output, we saw that `HEAD` named `master`.  Doing:

```
git checkout branch
```

tells Git not only to check out the specific commit that `branch` names, but also put the *name* `branch` into `HEAD`.  We say that HEAD is *attached* to the branch.  But we can *detach* it by putting a raw hash ID into `HEAD`, which we do by running:

```
git checkout 3bc5322
```

This does the same thing as having a branch name there, *except* ...

#### New commits move branches

When you make a *new* commit, Git writes the new commit pointing back to the current commit, then changes *the current branch* so that it points to the new commit.  For instance, if we add a new commit `D` to our three-commit `A-B-C` setup, the commits themselves look like this:

```
A <- B <- C <- D
```

But `D`'s name is one of those big ugly hash IDs, and there's no way we can remember that.  Instead, we have Git remember it for us—by writing it into the current branch's name.  If the current branch is `master`, this changes `master` so that it no longer points to `C`:

```
A <- B <- C <- D   <-- master
```

Now that `master` remembers `D` for us, the branch itself has grown!

But, here is the problem: the way Git knows which branch to update is that it's stored in `HEAD`.  If you have a detached HEAD, there is no current branch *name*.  In this case, Git remembers the new commit *only* as `HEAD`.  Suppose we add `D` while we have `B` checked out by hash ID:

```
A--B--C     <-- master
    \
     D      <-- HEAD
```

If we `git checkout master`, that overwrites `HEAD` with the name `master`, "forgetting" our new commit.

That's not really dangerous, unless maybe it is: maybe you wrote some really great code that you will [never be able to write again](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gh4zvQfDhi0), and now you've lost it, oh no!  So for this purpose, you can *create a new branch name* at any commit, *including* a detached HEAD, using `git checkout -b`:

```
git checkout -b newbranch
```

and now we have:

```
A--B--C     <-- master
    \
     D      <-- newbranch (HEAD)
```

Or, of course, you can give commit `B` a label, then check it out, then make your new commit `D`.  The point here is that it's the *commits* that really matter; the names just give us *ways to find them*.

#### There are many ways to name commits

You can use branch and tag names, but you can add a suffix and a count:

```
HEAD~1
```

for instance means "start at HEAD, but then walk back once to HEAD's parent".  (If the commit is a *merge commit*—one with more than one parent—the `~` suffix picks the *first* parent, every time.)  Or, you can use `@{...}` with `HEAD` or a branch name:

```
master@{1.week.ago}
```

which uses what Git calls the *reflog* for `master` to see which commit `master` named exactly one week ago (if that was a day you changed it several times, Git goes for exactly 7*24*60*60 seconds ago; Git is pretty literal here).

There are lots of other ways to find commits, including searching for text in commit *messages*.  Study [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) for more ways to name commits.